# How to remove just the index name and not the content in Pandas multiindex data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following tab delimited file (`mydata.txt`):

```
Set Coolthing   Route   Organ   Up  Down
set4    foo ID  LN  81  60
set4    bar ID  LN  542 92
set4    foo ID  LV  73  73
set4    bar ID  LV  143 78
set4    foo ID  SP  32  82
set4    bar ID  SP  90  129
```

And with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.io.parsers.read_table("http://dpaste.com/3ZTTVQH.txt")
df = df.pivot(index="Coolthing",columns="Organ")
df.drop('Set',axis=1,inplace=True)
df.drop('Route',axis=1,inplace=True)
```

I have the following data frame:

```
In [15]: df
Out[15]:
            Up           Down
Organ       LN   LV  SP    LN  LV   SP
Coolthing
bar        542  143  90    92  78  129
foo         81   73  32    60  73   82
```

Then using `df.to_html(index=True, justify="left")` create this html:

[image]

What I want to do is to remove the index names `Organ` and `Coolthing`. Resulting this:

```
             Up           Down
            LN   LV  SP    LN  LV   SP
bar        542  143  90    92  78  129
foo         81   73  32    60  73   82
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a `name` for single level names and `names` for multi-level names so for your example you need to do this to clear the names from index and columns:

```
In [372]:

df.index.name = None
df.columns.names = (None,None)
df
​
Out[372]:
      Up          Down         
      LN   LV  SP   LN  LV   SP
bar  542  143  90   92  78  129
foo   81   73  32   60  73   82
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just get/set the index via its name property. What you can do is set

```
    df.index.name = ""
```