# Pandas pivot_table preserve order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

```
>>> df
   A   B   C      D
0  foo one small  1
1  foo one large  2
2  foo one large  2
3  foo two small  3
4  foo two small  3
5  bar one large  4
6  bar one small  5
7  bar two small  6
8  bar two large  7
>>> table = pivot_table(df, values='D', index=['A', 'B'],
...                     columns=['C'], aggfunc=np.sum)
>>> table
          small  large
foo  one  1      4
     two  6      NaN
bar  one  5      4
     two  6      7
```

I want the output to be as shown above, but I get a sorted output.
bar comes above foo and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While creating `pivot_table`, the index is *automatically sorted*  alphabetically. Not only `foo` and `bar`, you may also notice `small` and `large` is sorted. If you want `foo` on top, you may need to `sort` them again using `sortlevel`. If you are expecting output as in [example here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html), then sorting on `A` and `C` both may be needed.

```
table.sortlevel(["A","B"], ascending= [False,True], sort_remaining=False, inplace=True)
table.sortlevel(["C"], axis=1, ascending=False,  sort_remaining=False, inplace=True)
print(table)
```

Output:

```
C        small  large
A   B                
foo one  1.0    4.0  
    two  6.0    NaN   
bar one  5.0    4.0  
    two  6.0    7.0
```

## Update:

To remove index names `A`, `B` and `C`:

```
table.columns.name = None
table.index.names = (None, None)
```

Comment: How do I remove C A B from the above given solution??
          small  large
foo  one  1      4
     two  6      NaN
bar  one  5      4
     two  6      7

Comment: For index there is multilevel i.e. you have `A` and `B` so you need `index.names`. You can take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/30254337/5916727 . I saw you mentioned you are beginner so, best thing would be to try., for e.g. what is returned by `table.index`, `table.cloumns.name` ......

Comment: +1 for the (obvious, in hindsight) suggestion about how to remove the index labels (if you get a NaN using None, simply use an empty string)

Answer (score 12):

Since [pandas 1.3.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew/v1.3.0.html), it's possible to specify `sort=False` in [`pd.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar"],
...                    "B": ["one", "one", "one", "two", "two", "one", "one", "two", "two"],
...                    "C": ["small", "large", "large", "small","small", "large", "small", "small", "large"],
...                    "D": [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
...                    "E": [2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9, 9]})
>>> pd.pivot_table(df, values='D', index=['A', 'B'], columns=['C'],
...                aggfunc='sum', sort=False)
C        large  small
A   B                
foo one    4.0    1.0
    two    NaN    6.0
bar one    4.0    5.0
    two    7.0    6.0
```

Answer (score 10):

I think pivot_table doesn't have an option for sorting, but groupby has:

```
df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C'], sort=False)['D'].sum().unstack('C')
Out: 
C        small  large
A   B                
foo one    1.0    4.0
    two    6.0    NaN
bar one    5.0    4.0
    two    6.0    7.0
```

You pass the grouping columns to groupby and for the ones you want to show as column values, you use unstack.

If you don't want the index names, rename them as None:

```
df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C'], sort=False)['D'].sum().rename_axis([None, None, None]).unstack(level=2)
Out: 
         small  large
foo one    1.0    4.0
    two    6.0    NaN
bar one    5.0    4.0
    two    6.0    7.0
```