# How to preserve column order in panda pivot for dates

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have the following dataframe:

```
x
Group Year_mon A   B   C
   0  Apr 2018 5%  6%  7%
   1  May 2018 4%  4%  2%
...
  15  Jun 2019 8%  6%  8%
```

I want to pivot this table such as all time values are in columns such for which I use :

```
y = x.pivot_table(columns='Year_mon', aggfunc=lambda x: ' '.join(x)).reset_index()
```

but the resultant data set is :

```
y
Year_mon  Group Apr 2018 Apr 2019 Aug 2018 Aug 2019....
       0      A       5%       4%       4%       3%
       1      B       6%       5%       7%       8%
```

but the expected dataset should be something like:

```
 Year_mon  Group Apr 2018 May 2018 Jun 2018 Jul 2018....Jun 2019
        0      A       5%       4%       4%       3%          8%
        1      B       6%       5%       7%       8%          6%
        ...
```

Now I searched and figured out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44988213/pandas-pivot-table-preserve-order) that columns are automatically ordered while pivoting and we need to manually sort it but in my example i have a dynamic list of months which will keep growing and I need to preserve the time order. How to go about it

Comment: Could you give an example of what you want the resultant data to look like?

Comment: If you convert to `Period` with `pd.to_datetime(df['Year_mon'], format='%b %Y').dt.to_period('M')`, normal sorting should suffice.

Comment: The issue is same in this case, period converts into dates again and not in the format '%b %Y'

Comment: You have a `PeriodIndex` then it's fairly simple to just do `df.columns = df.columns.strftime('%b %Y')` to get your text format. Just keep everything as a date, then convert **only when you really need to at the very end**. With `datetime` all the information and date transformations are readily available, which is why it's so useful. Not so much with the text format.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Year_mon` values are in chronological order in the starting DataFrame, then you can convert them to an ordered `category` dtype before pivoting:

```
x['Year_mon'] = pd.Categorical(x['Year_mon'], ordered=True)
```

If you pivot now, the columns should appear left-to-right in the same order as the month-year strings appear in the original DataFrame.

Comment: I specifically need to convert into text. I already have it in the date format. I'm in fact using       x['Year_mon'] = x['Year_mon_date'].apply(lambda x : x.strftime('%b %Y')) to create the Year_mon column

Comment: @hbabbar I see. In that case, I would suggest converting the string data type to `Categorical`! Will edit my answer.

Comment: I get the following exception : TypeError: cannot insert an item into a CategoricalIndex that is not already an existing category

Comment: @hbabbar, maybe you ran the command twice? A complete, copy-pastable example would help here!

Answer (score 0):

```
tuples = [a.strftime('%b-%y') if a!=All else a for a in df.columns]
df.columns = pd.multiindex.from_tuples(tuples)
```